# Nuxt3 and VueUse refDebounced and min 3 chars then trigger useFetch

Tags: vue.js, nuxt3, vueuse

Want to trigger useFetch after min 3 chars and also wait for 100 mS after each char.

Have also a strange thing that the value of searchTerm.value is always empty.

```
const searchTerm = ref('')

const debouncedFn = useDebounceFn(() => {
    if (searchTerm.value && searchTerm.value.length >= 3) {
      execute()
    }
  }, {delay: 50})

const {data, execute } = await useFetch('url', {
    headers: {
      access_token: 'token'
    },
    query: {
      query: **searchTerm.value** >> always be empty
    }
    watch: [
      debouncedFn
    ],
    immediate: false,
  })

<template>
    <input v-model="searchTerm">
</template>
```

Comment: `query: **searchTerm.value**` - it's always empty because you read it once on setup. Use `query: searchTerm` to not read the value eagerly. Does this solve the problem?